# Confusion about static methods in Java

Tags: java, static

As I understand `static`, it is that static methods can be called without an instance of the object needing to exist. So instead of making an object and calling the method on that object, you can just call the method on the class.

Now, I have a class `Main` that has the following object: `public ScribbleCanvas myCanvas;`. In the `ScribbleCanvas` class I would like to access a method of the `Main`-class.

Now, since there is already an instance of `Main` (since this called the `ScribbleCanvas`), how can I access a non-static method of this class? Or perhaps the better question - where is the error in my reasoning?

Comment: Are you sure there is already an instance of the Main class? Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: could you give more details? why do you need to call a method of Main from that class?

Comment: `ScribbleCanvas` is the name of the class. What does that have to do with the existence of an instance?

Comment: can you please show some code? if the function that used ScribbleCanvas can the Main class instance, it can pass the instance to the ScribbleCanvas . if not, you can make the function "public static" , and then it will be available for every function/class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a constructor or a setter for the `ScribbleCanvas` that takes a parameter as the current instance of `Main`.

```
ScribbleCanvas sc = new ScribbleCanvas(this);
```

or

```
sc.setMainClass(this);
```

And with those, you just reference a field to the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Main` instance as a member of `myCanvas` and use it.

Answer (score 1):

The below code explains how you should do it. The `testInstanceMethod` is been taken as an 
example for an instance method in Main class. This method should be accessible as well

```
public class ScribbleCanvas{

private Main mainObject = null;


public ScribbleCanvas(){

this.mainObject = new Main();
//Call instance method in mainObject (member instance)
this.mainObject.testInstanceMethod();
}

public void setMainObject(Main arg){
this.mainObject = arg;
}

public Main getMainObject(){
return this.mainObject;
}

}
```

For invoking static methods, you can directly put the Classname and invoke using DOT operator like `Main.testStaticMethod()` provided the method is accessible as well

Disclaimer : NOT tested / compiled

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you want to:

- Have an instance of the `Main` class, let's call it `myMain`.
- The instance will have an instance of the `ScribbleCanvas` class, called `myCanvas`
- From the `ScribbleCanvas` instance (`myCanvas`) have access to methods within `myMain`.

In order to do this you can:

- Declare a member of type `Main` within `ScribbleCanvas`, say `callingMain`
- Include a parameter of type `Main` (say `paramMain`) in the constructor for `ScribbleCanvas`
- In the constructor, store `paramMain` in `callingMain`
- From `Main`, pass in `this` to the constructor
- Within your code, you can refer to `callingMain.method()`

Does this help?